# How to get the Qna Maker "Q" from Analytics Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker, telemetry, ms-app-analytics

I have created my chatbot's knowledge base with Qna Maker and I am trying to visualize some statistics with Analytics Application Insights.

**What I want to do**

I would like to create a chart with the most requested Qna Maker questions.

**My problem**

I can't find the Qna Maker questions in the customDimensions traces on Analytics but only their Id :

[image]

**My question**

Is their a way to get the Qna Maker Question linked to this Id directly from the Analytics Application Insights tool ?

Thank you.

**PS :** I had to use "Q" instead of "Question" in the title due to Stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.

the only info you have in appinsights is whatever was submitted with the data.   so if they aren't sending the question (odd that they send the answer but not the question?) then you're out of luck.

As a workaround, you could create a custom table in your application insights instance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-import
and populate that table with the id and question.

then you could join those two things in analytics queries in the analytics tool or in workbooks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It may be a solution for a static knowledge base but mine is going to change over time and I couldn't find a way to create a dynamic custom table refering to my Qna Maker KB.

Comment: your other option then is to make a tool that uses the application insights REST api to query AI (https://dev.applicationinsights.io) and also query your knowledge base?

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for a query with question and answer linked through id, here is your answer:

```
requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer"
| project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
| parse name with *"/knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
| project KbId, timestamp, resultCode, duration, question, answer
```

This doesn't necessarily solve your issue but might be of help for other people looking for a simple report of question/answer to improve their QnA maker.

The sample could be found in the official documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that I came up with that will pull in the id of the knowlegebase question, the question the user typed, and the knowlegebase anwer. It also ties multiple questions together if they are from the same session.

I have not yet been able to find a way to identify a way to get the knowlegebase question associated to the id though.

```
requests
| where url endswith 'generateAnswer'
| project id, url, sessionId = extract('^[a-z0-9]{7}', 0, itemId)
| parse kind = regex url with *'(?i)knowledgebases/'knowlegeBaseId'/generateAnswer'
| join kind= inner
(
    traces
    | extend id = operation_ParentId
    | where message == 'QnAMaker GenerateAnswer'
    | extend userQuestion = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
    | extend knowlegeBaseQuestionId = tostring(customDimensions['Id'])
    | extend knowlegeBaseAnswer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
    | extend score = tostring(customDimensions['Score'])
)
on id
| where timestamp >= ago(10d)
| project knowlegeBaseId, timestamp, userQuestion, knowlegeBaseQuestionId, knowlegeBaseAnswer, score, sessionId
| order by timestamp asc
```