# How can I save some custom qna maker data in azure app insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I have set up an Azure Bot with Luis and QnA Maker (in C#, Bot Framework v4). I want to query the App Insights and get information about the questions asked together with their answer. I followed the answers here: [How to get the Qna Maker "Q" from Analytics Application Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712132/how-to-get-the-qna-maker-q-from-analytics-application-insights), and I was able to get them, but I need an additional field for storing the user role (it would be perfect if I could store it in the customDimension field).

I have followed the documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 and I added the custom field like this:

```
var telemetryProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "dialogId", myDialogId },
};

var results = await qna.GetAnswersAsync(context, opts, telemetryProperties);
```

Still, I don't know if the value is saved or where it is saved. I the live metrics I see that the information is sent, but I can't find it anywhere in the Analytics/Logs.

If you need any further information, let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked it in customEvents table of app insights analytics logs?

Comment: Yes, there are some customEvents with the name QnAMessage which contain more information, but my additional field is not there.

Comment: If you're using visual studio, when run the project, you can check the telemetry in the output window of VS. Could you please try to check if the dialogId is in the output window of VS?

Comment: I works! It was a problem that on certain cases the field was null. It's indeed in the customEvents table. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I summarized our comments as a post, it would be helpful for other. Could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the communication with op, the telemetry is eventually in the customEvents table of app insights analytics logs. Sometimes it does not exist due to the value is null.