# Add QnA users questions and answers to Insights telemetry in Node JS

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights, botframework

I need to send QnA users questions and answers to my Azure bot insights using telemetry. Already tried this tutorial :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

And this SO posts:

- [How to get the Qna Maker "Q" from Analytics Application Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712132/how-to-get-the-qna-maker-q-from-analytics-application-insights)
- [How can I save some custom qna maker data in azure app insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455724/how-can-i-save-some-custom-qna-maker-data-in-azure-app-insights)

Thing is, first it's done for LUIS and gives no additional info to Insights, also nothing for QnA...second ones are written for C#...

I need to send question and answer to customEvents logs on Azure insights using NodeJS but I can't find how, any help ?

Thanks in advance.

///// EDIT:

Here's what I got so far (only posted the code related to the telemetry and QnA that's already working fine):

Index.js

```
const { ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient, TelemetryInitializerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-applicationinsights');
const { TelemetryLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-core');

function getTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey) {
    if (instrumentationKey) {
        return new ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey);
    }
    return new NullTelemetryClient();
}

const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());


var telemetryClient = getTelemetryClient(process.env.InstrumentationKey);
var telemetryLoggerMiddleware = new TelemetryLoggerMiddleware(telemetryClient);
var initializerMiddleware = new TelemetryInitializerMiddleware(telemetryLoggerMiddleware);
adapter.use(initializerMiddleware);


const mybot = new MYBOT(conversationState,userState, telemetryClient);
```

mybot.js

```
class MYBOT extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(conversationState,userState,telemetryClient) {
        super();

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }
}

//This is how I get my qna result:
console.log(this.telemetryClient);
var result = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);
```

As You can see, I pass the telemetryClient to the bot file, and if I console log that item I get the complete telemetry object, but how I pass it the user question and answer so its save on insights customevents ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to it, in case people that's looking for one of the possible solutions for Node may need it :

Basically, We use the same telemetry code process described in oficial documentation for instancing telemetry on index.js :

```
const { ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient, TelemetryInitializerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-applicationinsights');
const { TelemetryLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-core');

function getTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey) {
    if (instrumentationKey) {
        return new ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey);
    }
    return new NullTelemetryClient();
}

const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());


var telemetryClient = getTelemetryClient(process.env.InstrumentationKey);
var telemetryLoggerMiddleware = new TelemetryLoggerMiddleware(telemetryClient);
var initializerMiddleware = new TelemetryInitializerMiddleware(telemetryLoggerMiddleware);
adapter.use(initializerMiddleware);


const mybot = new MYBOT(conversationState,userState, telemetryClient);
```

Then, we pass it to the bot file (bot.js or the one you´re using):

```
class MYBOT extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(conversationState,userState,telemetryClient) {
        super();

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }
}
```

And later in code, You can use **telemetry.trackEvent** method (Official docs are only in C#), but basically, it allows you to create a custom event you want to track in specifics events in your code, like when You're bot has an error or doesn´t found an answer to user. Code according to previous lines would be like this:

```
this.telemetryClient.trackEvent(
        {name: "myEvent", 
         properties: {my_user_question: 'Context activity text here or your captured question', 
         my_bot_answer: 'bot reply or whatever'}
        }
); // name and properties are part of the sintaxys, values inside properties object as you may need.
```

That way, on Azure insights customEvents model You will see records captured with the event name you used, also, with the properties objects as a dict in customdimensions field.